# Set Microsoft Ajax Options, SP.RequestExecutor.js

Tags: sharepoint-addin, ajax

I´m using  `SP.RequestExecutor.js` to make CORS calls in a sharepoint-hosted add-in. `executor.executeAsync` uses the Microsoft Ajax library, right?

If it's correct, is there a way to set Ajax options, like `jQuery.ajax({beforeSend:fn})`?

**Update note**

It's a requirement to use SP.RequestExecutor.js to natively handle digestvalue and to make cross site collections calls.

Answer (score 1):

In **SharePoint Hosted App**, You can use `jQuery.ajax` directly. There is no need to use `SP.RequestExecutor.js`. `SP.RequestExecutor.js` does not have any option like 
`beforeSend:fn`. In **SharePoint Hosted App**, execute `jQuery.ajax` request like following:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
   beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
   },
   complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
   }
   // ......
 });
```

If you need to execute request in **Host Web**, then use `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`. For **App Web**, use `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. It's a requirement to use SP.RequestExecutor.js to natively handling digestvalue and to make cross site collections calls. Microsoft Ajax has options (OnBegin , OnComplete , OnSuccess, OnFailure) and can be set in a web forms application. So, I'm still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Why do u need `beforeSend:fn` in `SP.RequestExecutor.js`. Can you share the requirement? The I will try to give a wayaround with `SP.RequestExecutor.js`

Comment: The goal was to instantiate a progress bar for a upload process. But I've written some js to create a new XMLHttpRequest instance and added a modXHR.upload.addEventListener('loadstart', fn)